# Is there an R package with a generalized class of data.frame in which a column can be an array (or how do I define such a class)?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have been wondering about this for a long time. The data.frame class in base R only allow the columns to be vectors. I was looking for a package which generalize this so that each "column" can be a 2-d or even n-d array with similar methods to the original class data.frame such as sub-setting with "[]", merge, aggregate, etc.

My reason for such a class is to deal with Monte Carlo simulation data. For example, for each simulation the result can be expressed as a data frame in which the row indices are dates, and columns include character and numeric. If I simulate 1000 times then I get 1000 such data frames. If there is a class in R with which I can store the results in one object and has the convenience of most of the data.frame methods, it'll make my coding a lot easier.

As I couldn't find such a package I attempted to create my own with no success. I came across this package "S4Vectors" with a "DataFrame" class, which "supports the storage of any type of object (with length and [ methods) as columns." Here is my attempt.

    `library(S4Vectors)
    test <- matrix(1:6,2,3)
    test1 <- matrix(7:12,2,3)
    setClass("Column", slots=list(), contains = "matrix")
    setMethod("length", "Column", function(x) {nrow(x)})
    '[.Column' <- function(x, i, j, ...) {
      i <- ((i-1)*ncol(x)+1):(i*(ncol(x)))
      NextMethod()
    }
    testColumn <- new("Column", test)
    testColumn1 <- new("Column", test1)
    length(testColumn)
    testColumn[1]
    testDataFrame <- DataFrame(Col1 = testColumn, Col2 = testColumn1)`

I did get the length and [ method to work but the last statement gives an error "cannot coerce class "Column" to a DataFrame".

Has anyone ever tried to do something similar?

Update: Thanks to G. Grothendieck I now know a data frame can take a matrix as a column by using the I() function. Now I am wondering if there is way to preserve such a structure in all operations. An example would be to aggregate the data frame

`data.frame(v = c(1,1,2,2), m = I(diag(4)))`

by v so that the result is

`data.frame(v = c(1,2), m = I(matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1), 2, 4, byrow = T)))`.

Comment: You may find the concept of nested dataframes from the `tidyverse` useful. Check it out (starts at 25.2.1): https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

data frames do allow matrix columns:

```
m <- diag(4)
v <- 1:4
DF <- data.frame(v, m = I(m))
str(DF)
```

giving:

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ v: int  1 2 3 4
 $ m: 'AsIs' num [1:4, 1:4] 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
```

### Update 1

The R `aggregate` function can create matrix columns.  For example,

```
DF <- data.frame(v = 1:4, g = c(1, 1, 2, 2))
ag <- aggregate(v ~ g, DF, function(x) c(sum = sum(x), mean = mean(x)))
str(ag)
```

giving:

```
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ g: num  1 2
 $ v: num [1:2, 1:2] 3 7 1.5 3.5
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr  "sum" "mean"
```

### Update 2

I don't think the aggregation discussed in the comments is nicely supported in R but you can use the following workaround:

```
m <- matrix(1:16, 4)
v <- c(1, 1, 2, 2)
DF <- data.frame(v, m = I(m))

nr <- nrow(DF)
ag2 <- aggregate(list(sum = 1:nr), DF["v"], function(ix) colSums(DF$m[ix, ]))
str(ag2)
```

giving:

```
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ v  : num  1 2
 $ sum: num [1:2, 1:4] 3 7 11 15 19 23 27 31
```

Comment: Oh that is surprising. I do know that you can pass matrix as columns when creating a data frame, but I thought that would make each column of the matrix a column by itself in the data frame.

Comment: Note the difference between `data.frame(v, m)` and `data.frame(v, I(m))`

Comment: The problem now becomes that aggregating such a data frame does not preserve the structure, or at least I don't know how to do it. Using your example with a small change so that v <- c(1,1,2,2), how do I aggregate this data frame by v so that the result has two variables, 2 obs. with the second column still being a matrix with 4 columns?

Comment: I am not clear on the question. I have added an example that shows that aggregate does indeed produce matrix columns.

Comment: Thank you for spending time answering my questions. To be more specific, my questions is that if 
`DF <- data.frame(c(1,1,2,2), m = I(diag(4)))`, how do I aggregate (e.g. sum) this data frame so that the result is `data.frame(c(1,2), m = I(matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1), 2, 4, byrow = T)))`

Comment: See Update 2 just added.

Comment: That works great. I won't call it a workaround at all. Still wondering if this can be generalized to n-d arrays but this is what I need for my use case anyway.